# How to open a path in remote machine and write a file in that path using java

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

Based on user input data and database data, i need to create a file and place it in remote machine. So the better way i could think of was connect to remote machine and write the file directly there. So far using `JSch` i connected to remote machine. but i have no idea how to write a file in a particular location `(root/usr/path/)` in this path i need to write and place a file `(ddr12213124.NEW or ddr12213124.CSV)`.

I have attached the code for connecting to remote machine

```
package com.trial.classes;

import java.io.InputStream;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.UserInfo;

public class transferFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession("ragesh", "10.0.0.1", 22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword("password");
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected to session successfully");
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected to Channel successfully");
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
    }
}
```

Now i would like to create a file `(ddr12213124.NEW or ddr12213124.CSV)` and place it in the path `root/usr/path/`

I asked this question earlier but it was marked duplicate and i was asked to raise a new question. This is not duplicate. No appropriate answer was found so far in the link that was posted earlier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use JSch to put a file to the remote directory and if the directory does not exist, then create it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838767/use-jsch-to-put-a-file-to-the-remote-directory-and-if-the-directory-does-not-exi)

Comment: @Sanjeev nope..!! I would like to create a notepad file.. enter few data inside that file and save it with a specific extension like .NEW or .CSV

Comment: how do i open a particular path.. like option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://user@example.com/
put examplefile.txt /home/user/
exit
This is a winscp script how do i make java do this ??

Comment: For that create a file using FileIO and then use ChannelSFTP#put method to place your file

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ChannelSFTP#put](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put(java.lang.String,%20int)) method to write a file to remote directory. there are several flavors of the put method and you can use any one as per your needs. Here is a sample code to write a File from Local System to remote system:

```
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = jsch.getSession("ragesh", "10.0.0.1", 22);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setPassword("password");
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected to session successfully");
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected to Channel successfully");
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        // this will read file with the name test.txt and write to remote directory
        sftpChannel.cd("/root/usr/path");
        File f = new File("test.txt");
        sftpChannel.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName()); // here you can also change the target file name by replacing f.getName() with your choice of name

        sftpChannel.exit();
        session.disconnect();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

Comment: i am getting this  error while running the code 

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Comment: Run the JVM with -XX:MaxHeapSize=256m (or any big number), and possibly -Xmx512m

Comment: How did you set these options ?

Comment: ERROR : Could not find or load mainclass myClass

Comment: `java -Xmx1024m com.trial.classes.transferFile`

Comment: Jsch doesn't use an unusual amount of memory. Having trouble getting the JVM to start is out of scope for this question.